# Why exactly is it that light cannot escape a black hole?

Tags: gravity, black-holes

I understand that the gravity has to have a pull greater than the speed of light, but I thought that when gravity pulls light it doesn't accelerate it only blue-shifts it. So then why does gravity only pull light in when it has a g force greater than its velocity?

Also is there any evidence that gravity blueshifts light

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a black hole black?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28297/)

Comment: Also see the question [If you shoot a light beam behind the event horizon of a black hole, what happens to the light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/106484/if-you-shoot-a-light-beam-behind-the-event-horizon-of-a-black-hole-what-happens). This is the same calculation as the one I linked, but phrased in a slightly more user friendly way (still not especially non-nerd friendly though!).

Comment: Re the last question, see the [Pound-Rebka experiment](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=pound+rebka).