# It's about black holes

Tags: black-holes

If is was to stand deep inside the center of a black hole and was to point a light gun straight up at the center of the event horizon, would the beam of light make it out of the black hole?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't you escape a black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25369/)

Comment: First of all, the study for the centre of the Black hole is still going on and secondly, if you hit the centre of the Black hole with a beam of light, then the light would never escape. When speaking with the reference to Scale you and your light beam are like microbes for a Black hole.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If you shoot a light beam behind the event horizon of a black hole, what happens to the light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106484/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Light from OUTSIDE the black hole that passes through the event horizon cannot escape, and observers from the outside will never see light emerging from the interior. I'm not sure what you mean by suggesting that one could stand deep inside with a flashlight. Absent a quantum theory of gravity, we really don't know how physics behaves in the center of a black hole (except, of course, that a person surviving with an intact flashlight is impossible). If your followup question concerns what things are like inside, I'm afraid you will be disappointed.

Comment: My second question is this, if the gravitational pull of a black hole is strong enough to stop the speed of light, then wouldn't a quasar have to travel faster than the speed of light, at some point, to break the gravitational pull at the event horizon?

Comment: A quasar surrounds a black hole. The light emitted is generated by the material surrounding the event horizon as it is heated by the immense tidal forces near the black hole. None of the light actually comes from inside.